# How to get the height and width of rendered elements in ECharts?

Tags: javascript, charts, echarts

How can I retrieve the height and width of rendered elements in ECharts, such as visualMap and legends? I need to obtain the exact dimensions of these elements for further calculations and adjustments within my application.

I've checked the ECharts documentation and API reference, but couldn't find a direct method or property to access the height and width. Is there a way to achieve this programmatically?